# "Map iterator is not a function" in OpenFL

Tags: iterator, haxe, openfl

I was building my project for Windows and everything was working fine. Now I started building it in HTML5 and I'm getting an error with map iterators:

```
for (entryMap in mapStruct.map)
{
    var array:Array<Dynamic> = entryMap;
    var keyObj = getJSONField(array[0], mapStruct.keyType);
    var valueObj = getJSONField(array[1], mapStruct.valueType);

    map.set(keyObj, valueObj);
}
```

And I get this error:

> Exception name: TypeError: mapStruct.map.iterator is not a function

My project was working fine for Windows, but I don't know what to do, I need to use map like this.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to guess what is mapStruct without any success.
It looks like your aren't looping on a map in the right way...
Let's see some examples:

```
var map = ["hello" => 1, "world" => 4];

for (value in map)
{
    trace('value: $value');
}
```

returns:

```
value: 1
value: 4
```

Here you have the [link](http://try.haxe.org/#69E66) to try it online.

On the other hand, if you want to get either key and value, you should iterate it this way:

```
var map = ["hello" => 1, "world" => 4];

for (key in map.keys())
{
    trace('key: $key value: ${map[key]}');
}
```

* Note the `keys` method call

And it returns:

```
key: hello value: 1
key: world value: 4
```

Here's the 'Try Haxe' [link](http://try.haxe.org/#dF1C7) for it

if I knew which type `mapStruct` is, I'd probably help you more